# Get System Activation email link

Tags: craft3, modules, craft-pro

On my site a type of user can add new clients and I wanted to automate the activation email, so that when a new user is added then the client will get the activation email.
But I'm getting an error that the activation $link is missing any idea how to get that parameter? This is what I have so far.

```
Craft::$app->elements->on(Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT, function(ElementEvent $event) {

      if ($event->element instanceof \craft\elements\User) {
        
        $user = $event->element;
       

        if($event->isNew) {
          
          Craft::$app
          ->getMailer()
          ->composeFromKey('after_activate_user')
          ->setTo($user)
          ->send();
        }
      }
    });
```

Digging through some code I saw that you can pass a link parameter like this:

```
 ->composeFromKey('after_activate_user', ['link' => Template::raw($link)])
```

But not sure where I can retrieve this $link

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than assembling the email yourself, you can just call the [sendActivationEmail](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-users.html#method-sendactivationemail) method in Craft:

```
if ($event->isNew) {
    Craft::$app->getUsers()->sendActivationEmail($user);
}
```

That will automatically generate the activation link for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want full control on the activation email site/language/template you just can't rely on sendActivationEmail(). You can do this instead:

```
use craft\mail\Message;

// get activation link
$verifyUrl = Craft::$app->users->getEmailVerifyUrl($user);

// create email
$msg = new Message();
$msg->setTo($user->email);
$msg->setSubject('Activate your account');

// compose the HTML body where you will output verifyUrl link
$template = Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('path/to/template', [
   'user' => $user,
   'verifyUrl' => $verifyUrl
]); 
$msg->setHtmlBody($template);

// finally send the email
$msg->send();
```